# Screen door closer is pulling the door jamb

Tags: doors, door-frame

When I got this new door closer attached and assembled, opening the door caused the door jamb to bend with the closer arm. I tried to secure the door jamb with several screws but that didn’t help. Is the next step to remove the door jamb? My thought is to tear it out and then replace it with another piece of wood that is more securely (glued? nailed?) into place. Is that the most logical next step? Thank you.[image]

Comment: You could get a piece of flat aluminum bar stock and jam it between the jambs.  That could keep the wood from bending with the door closer.  Any chance you're simply opening the door too far?